# I don't know why we need setters for this program when the constructor does the same job

Tags: java

I don't know why we need setters for this program when the constructor does the same job.
I already referenced name to aName in the constructor.
I dont know why you have to do the same thing in the setter.
Same with salary = aSalary

```
public class Employer
{
    private String name;
    private double salary;

    public Employer(String aName, double aSalary)
    {
        name = aName;//I already referenced name to aName here
        salary = aSalary;
    }

    public void setName(String aName)
    {
        name = aName;//I don't know why I have to do it again here
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setSalary(double aSalary)
    {
        salary = aSalary;//I dont know why we do it here too
    }

    public double getSalary()
    {
        return salary;
    }
```

Please Help!!!

Comment: At a broad level, it is essentially because you have by design chosen this class objects to be mutable. If you don't want to change the object at a later stage, you can remove the setters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Setter and Constructor confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163598/java-setter-and-constructor-confusion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because nobody ever changes their name or salary?

```
Employer e = new Employer("Bruce Jenner", 1.0);
// time passes
e.setName("Caitlyn Jenner");
```